# PostgreSQL Processor Queue Length

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, performance-tuning

Is there a similar metric to MSSQL's `Processor Queue Length` in PostgreSQL? I had a situation recently where a system ran several concurrent long-running queries that essentially blocked all other queries from running. In MSSQL, I would have had an alert that checks for this metric reaching an undesirable level. In PostgreSQL, my only option is reactionary, in that, I would alert on queries that are running for an undesirable length of time (`pg_stat_activity`), but that doesn't exactly translate to indicating there are no more CPUs remaining to service other queries. Additionally, the PQL metric helps to indicate that either database tuning is required or additional CPUs could be necessary for the system to process optimally.

Comment: Isn't 'Processor Queue Length' also 'reactionary'?  It doesn't seem to do anything, it just presents itself to you for your inspection and then your reaction.

Comment: "several concurrent long-running queries that essentially blocked all other queries from running".  CPU overload certainly wouldn't block other queries from running, it would just make them slower as they need to share CPU.  If they were really blocked, it must be something else going on, like table locks, or maybe a connection pooler you had set up which limits entry.

Comment: @jjanes yes, still reactionary. in MSSQL, this metric is extremely valuable because it indicates a backlog of queries that could be ran had you more CPU cores available. that is a good indicator that performance tuning needs to be done, and if it can't be done, the instance needs to be scaled for the workload.

"CPU overload certainly wouldn't block other queries from running"

It absolutely does, in MSSQL, and therefore I'm trying to determine if the same occurs in PostreSQL and what I can measure to respond to it.

Comment: It does not occur that way in PostgreSQL, they just share CPU unless you have a connection pooler or something.  Looking at the system CPU load (like with `top`) is the best way to determine the CPU load.  In general, PostgreSQL mostly relies on the OS doing its stuff, rather than reimplementing that stuff itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of those who may not be familiar with what "Processor Queue Length" means in SQL Server:

> **[System: Processor Queue Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/monitor-cpu-usage?view=sql-server-ver16)**
>
> Corresponds to the number of threads waiting for processor time. A processor bottleneck develops when threads of a process require more processor cycles than are available.

Since all Postgres processes are single-threaded, the usual run queue length or the load average metrics at the OS level will be a good approximation.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it explains well enough that PostgreSQL and MSSQL don't operate the same way with CPU cores and resources. Where an MSSQL server could block queries from entering a runnable state while not being at 100% CPU usage, PostgreSQL would not do that (other than the obvious with locks, etc). Sadly, in RDS, where my instances live, the OS information on CPU usage is not exposed well, but it also won't help me much either.